# Handle 100 request per minute with micro service

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, microservices, cloud-foundry

I’ve node.js application which is should handle the following

> 1. Get zip files extract those files (js module  files with some key and value - maximum 20 files but typically its 5-8 files for each
>      request)
> 2. Do some analyzing on those files and create new files from it and send it back to the client (if the request was with 5 files the
>      analyzing should return the same 5 new files etc…)
> 3. zip this new files and send it back to the client

I’ve created the module that do the analyzing which works ok, for about 10 files it takes about 250-300 ms to do the analysis and create the new files.

Lets assume I need to serve 100 clients that can do this

Now I want to create some `stateless` micro service that warp this functionality and do basically

```
get zip
extract zip
manipulate 
zip
send files
```

For that I want to create a `micro service` (stateless) in the cloud ( I want to deploy it to the cloud ( cloud foundry / Heroku  ) 
that should handle it 
And my question here is how should I handle multiple request? , let say i’ve 100 request per minute …
I understand that is should work **async** but still i’m afraid that for 10 or more request my app will crushed …

queue? scaling?

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that is should work async but still, I’m afraid that for 10 or more request my app will be crushed

```
I believe you have a bad idea on what a stateless server is.
```

Stateless servers are powerful, scalable and extensible. Stateless servers can handle more than the requests mentioned by you without getting crushed until you've enough credits in your cloud billing account -- at least this is whole reason why we use stateless servers

Go for it, your application can handle any number of requests :)

If you're still worried, just try splitting up your application. Like - let one of your function do the extraction and once done, it can request to analysis function to start its job. You can communicate with your different stateless servers using pub/sub or API end-points (just check the docs)